# Detect which target flash player version my .swf is exported to

Tags: flash

I have currently exported a .swf file with target version 10.1

My issue is that I have a another person claiming their system tells them that the .swf is exported for flash player 11.

Is there some tool - online or a part of flash that I can run my .swf through to detect the target version of the .swf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open up the swf with a hex editor or read in the file through a program and output the first 4 bytes. You are basically looking for the 4th byte which tells which version of flash it is created for. It looks as though this originally only updated per major flash version (8,9,10, etc...) but now it seems like it changes per minor version (11.1, 11.2 ...)

I did some digging with my editor and mapped the following hex values to the flash version they were exported for:

```
11.4 => 0x11
11.3 => 0x10
11.2 => 0x0F
11.1 => 0x0E
10.3 => 0x0C
10.2 => 0x0B
10.1, 10.0 => 0x0A
9.0 =>  0x09
8.0 =>  0x08
...
...
```

See example below of version 6.x (top) and version 11.4 (bottom). Notice the 4th byte of each (06 and 11) That is what you are looking for

[image: hex]

My hex editor of choice for mac: http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/

Here is a link to a forum that discussed the code to do it programmatically in [php](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?491201-PHP-How-to-detect-what-version-of-flash-a-swf-file-is)